# Freeswitch WebRTC to SIP

Tags: google-chrome, websocket, sip, webrtc, freeswitch

I have a freeswitch set up to Bridge the incoming websocket request (using sip.js) to a voice conference bridge in the backend. I have everything working except the SIP message that the voice conference bridge sends to freeswitch doesn't get delivered to the webclient
Below is the message that freeswitch receives from voice bridge and doesn't forward it to the websocket chrome client: (`10.39.65.229` is the freeswitch IP and web client registers as 1003)

```
 MESSAGE sip:1003@10.21.75.221 SIP/2.0
   Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 10.39.65.229;rport;branch=z9hG4bKKtvaSmXt1S4Qj
   Max-Forwards: 70
   From: <sip:18773092073_892327789_Speaker@10.21.70.85>;tag=4f4ddc2b
   To: <sip:1003@10.21.75.221>
   Call-ID: 3b0c33f0-a798-4b9c-908a-b10160e26f82
   CSeq: 60535928 MESSAGE
   Contact: <sip:10.39.65.229>
   User-Agent: FreeSWITCH-mod_sofia/1.4.3+git~20140519T173831Z~49047462fe~64bit
   Allow: INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, OPTIONS, MESSAGE, INFO, UPDATE, REGISTER, REFER, NOTIFY, PUBLISH, SUBSCRIBE
   Supported: path, replaces
   Content-Type: text/plain
   Content-Length: 132
   X-FS-Sending-Message: 9219cac6-79e8-4212-b00c-142379234c8e


   NOTIFY-JOIN 23899467 VoIP 271 Moderator strict false muted unhold
   NOTIFY-JOIN 23899639 VoIP 1003 Speaker false false unmuted unhold
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this is an initial request from your FreeSWITCH instance to your SIP.js client, since there is no to-tag or route set.

For this to work, you would have to be registering your SIP.js client to the FreeSWITCH server to be to receive initial requests.

If you are registered, as you say you are, then some thing is broken since the RURI in the request is not a valid websockets target.  It would be some thing like XXXXXXXXX.invalid.  Also the packet is leaving FreeSWITCH UDP based on the Via header, that obviously wont work.

Can you call your SIP.js client through FreeSWITCH from another client to verify that your registration is working, and that you can receive initial requests?

I would suggest you post this to our SIP.js google group so we can better understand your problem.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/sip_js

I suspect you are hooked into the event stream and using mod_sms send_message, to notify your SIP.js client of conference events.

If so, you should not be targeting the IP of your SIP.js client, but rather the IP of your FreeSWITCH instance so that it will perform a registration lookup, then send to your client over its websocket connection.